# How to save multiple dates in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have 2 models property and property dates.
i need to save multiple start date and end date for a property in property dates tables
table fields(property_id,start_date_end_date)
my model tables

```html
`class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :property_dates
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :property_dates
end`
```

```html
`class PropertyDate < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :property
end`
```

my controller

```html
class Users::PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_properties, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @properties =  Property.where(:user_id=>current_user.id)
  end

  def list
    @properties = Property.all
  end

  def show

  end

 
  def new
   @property= Property.new
  end

  
  def edit
  end

  def create
    @property = Property.new(properties_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
 format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.update(properties_params)
        format.json { render :back, status: :ok, location: @property }
      else
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 
  def destroy
    @property.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to  :back, notice: 'Property was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_properties
      @property = Property.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def properties_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:Space_name,:user_id,:address,:pincode,:image,property_dates_attributes: [ :start_date, :end_date ])
```

form property form i need to select multiple dates and need to save to property_dates table

my form.html.erb

```html
 `<%= simple_nested_form_for ([:users,@property])  do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :property_dates do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_field :start_date%>
    <%= p.text_field :end_date%>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>`
```

When i write form it is not visible in my form. Why it is happening like that? Any error in my code. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it:

```
def new
  @property= Property.new
  @property.property_dates.build
end
```